# How to restore folders in outlook7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook

i was deleting emails from outlook 7 yesterday from a couple of new folders in my personal folders I've made but today when i opened my mail box those folders are missing and here isn't any + sign either besides inbox to click open the list. how can it be restored if its deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't restore deleted folders. You can only restore deleted items (using either Deleted Items folder or Exchange Server's feature Recover Deleted Items).